# Eager Loading Laravel Eloquent

Tags: orm, laravel, eloquent

I have a quick and straightforward question. Which of the following queries is preferred while working with Eloquent ORM in Laravel?

```
$post = Post::with(array('user', 'comments.from'))->find($id);
$post = Post::with(array('user', 'comments.from'))->where('postID', $id)->get();
```

I'm struggling to find the difference between ->find and ->get with eager loading.

postID is my primary key in the posts table above. Both performance are nearly identical via my debugger and each run 8 queries.

If anyone can shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. This is what you should use; it will return one result model:

   ```
   $post = Post::with(array('user', 'comments.from'))->find($id);
   ```
2. This will return a collection of results (even if there's only one):

   ```
   $post = Post::with(array('user', 'comments.from'))->where('postID', $id)->get();
   ```
3. Instead of method 2, what you probably mean to do is this:

   ```
   $post = Post::with(array('user', 'comments.from'))->where('postID', $id)->first();
   ```

Methods 1 and 3 will basically get you the exact same result. Method 1 is more adaptable because it'll continue to work if you change the primary key for the table. It's also faster than the other two methods because it doesn't construct a collection of models.

By the way,this has nothing to do with the eager-loading, as these functions will all work the same on any query.

Comment: Is this even considered eager loading?

Comment: @user1011713 barely lol. with() and load() are for eager-loading in Laravel, but in this instance, you're just using them to load additional information into your model. If you were actually getting a collection of models, such as Post::with('comments')->get() to get all of your posts with their comments, it would be considered eager-loading because you're retrieving all of the data with just 2 queries, as opposed to n + 1 queries.

Comment: Any ideas how I could eager load the relationship?

Comment: @user1011713 it's irrelevant unless you're working with multiple posts. Otherwise, you'd do something like the Book method here http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading